# Complex manifolds $X$ with $TX \to X$ smoothly but not holomorphically trivial

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I am aware that there exist holomorphic vector bundles $E \to X$ that are smoothly trivial but not holomorphically so. For example, I think the following example works: let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g > 0$, and let $E = \mathcal O(D)$, where $D$ is a nonprincipal divisor on $X$ of degree $0$.

However, is it possible for a holomorphic *tangent* bundle $TX \to X$ to be smoothly trivial, and yet have no globally nonvanishing holomorphic sections?

**EDIT:** Added the word “holomorphic” in the last question.

Comment: The manifolds you are finding are just those who are Calabi--Yau but not (holomorphically) parallelizable.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks. After googling, I found existence proofs of such manifolds, but are there any concrete examples?